# MariaDB - Cannot connect to MariaDB instance from Dbeaver using correct password

Tags: mysql, mariadb, dbeaver

I am trying to connect to a localhost instance of MariaDb on port 3306.
I'm well aware that root cannot use localhost because of MariaDb specifications so I created
another user from the command line with password 'root' and all privileges granted to my 'test' database:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
GRANT ALL privileges ON `test`.* TO 'myuser'@localhost;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I try to open a connection from DBeaver with the correct password and username, an error appears:

> Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>   Current charset is windows-1251. If password has been set using other
>   charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'

Why does it happen? Is it because of some password hashing algorithms mismatch between DBeaver and MariaDB's instance? How do I fix this and connect successfuly?

Comment: Upgrade mariadb and see if the bug is solved.

Answer (score 4):

You have to to go to DriverProperties and enter the encoding you have used to encode password(UTF-8). This is very common when you use docker image to run maria db on your local  Refer the below image.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you wanna fix this warning to all connections (not just single one) you need to configure driver's general properties.

1. In dbeaver go to Database -> Driver Manager
2. Edit MariaDB/MySQL driver
   [image: d]
3. Tab `Driver properties`, Add new User property
   `passwordCharacterEncoding` : `UTF-8`
   [image]
4. Voila, it works for all connections use edited driver

Source: [mariaDB driver's parameters](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#optional-url-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue these days and didn’t find an answer online. I know it’s late, but for anyone who’s still suffering from this same problem, it’s seem to be a bug with Dbeaver or could be one...

Everytime I copy and paste the database and the username I get this exactly error! When I type it directly in the field I can connect successfully.

I would try this before getting mad

Comment: This worked for me. I didn't have to do any of the encoding changes in the other answers, just had to type it rather than copy/paste. Running Windows11.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's an encoding issue.

Before you create a new connection you should check the preferences here: [encoding preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma9I6.png)

It worked for me as I changed it to UTF-8.

Comment: The exception clearly says to set passwordCharacterEncoding. I could replicate the issue by pulling a mariadb docker image and try connecting to it from mariadb. I could only fix it by providing the passwordCharacterEncoding parameter as UTF-8