# MariaDB - Unable to login via user - error in password character encoding

Tags: mariadb, passwords

I created a new user for the existing DB, however I am unable to login via the new user. I get the following error. I use DBeaver client. MariaDB runs as docker container.

Error:

`Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'`

I saw some solutions regarding this problem, however I want to know the reason this happens and better solution other than uninstalling DB etc.

Comment: If you're creating user using an external tool, that may have caused it. Probably related https://stackoverflow.com/a/67217306/10910692 .

Comment: Did not solve my problem, but looks like possible solution. Will update if anything else works