# How to Access a AWS RDS with a CNAME hostname rather than Configuration Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-aurora, datagrip

I have a simple question which I am not finding in Stackoverflow even though this process of generating a db auth token has been asked many times but would like clarification on this if anyone can help.

This is all being tested currently and the process is like so:

1. I created my user with the following SQL script:

```
CREATE USER 'readonly'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH AWSAuthenticationPlugin AS 'RDS';
GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'readonly'@'%';
ALTER USER 'readonly'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

2. From here, I then generated the db auth token using the CNAME record of the hostname which holds my Writer configuration endpoint.

```
aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname rds-dev-mysql56.lock.internal --port 3306 --region us-east-1 --username readonly
```

3. Once I grab the token to sign in through my Datagrip IDE, I receive this error:

   [28000][1045] Could not connect to address=(host=rds-dev-mysql56.lock.internal)(port=3306)(type=master) : (conn=107783568) Access denied for user 'readonly'@'IP' (using password: YES) Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding' [28000][1045] (conn=107783568) Access denied for user 'readonly'@'IP' (using password: YES) Current charset is UTF-8. If password has been set using other charset, consider using option 'passwordCharacterEncoding'
4. I then followed this where the AWS RDS MySQL `passwordCharacterEncoding` should be added with `utf8` like in this post: [MariaDB - Cannot connect to MariaDB instance from Dbeaver using correct password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59577312/mariadb-cannot-connect-to-mariadb-instance-from-dbeaver-using-correct-password). However, with this change I get a new error:

   [28000][1045] Could not connect to address=(host=rds-dev-mysql56.lock.internal)(port=3306)(type=master) : (conn=107785323) Access denied for user 'readonly'@'IP' (using password: YES) [28000][1045] (conn=107785323) Access denied for user 'readonly'@'IP' (using password: YES)
5. It's only when I directly grab the Writer instance Configuration
   endpoint that this works where I am able to sign in.

So my question is, Do CNAME records work with generating the db auth token? I have read online that CNAME records don't work well with SSL/TLS encryption since I enabled `REQUIRE SSL`. Would appreciate any help.

EDIT: Added the error output in my Datagrip IDE and added link following instructions on the `passwordCharacterEncoding`.

EDIT 2: In the Datagrip IDE, I have SSL enabled and the following information. The token that is created is pasted where `Password` which does not work with the CNAME record:
[image]

However, as for how I get it to work with the Writer instance Configuration Endpoint, I enter the following to generate the token:
`aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname rds-dev-mysql56.cluster-23423423fd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port 3306 --region us-east-1 --username readonly`

This allows me to grab the token and successfully enter the database. I hope this is enough information.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem... are you sure you have *networking* access to `rds-dev-mysql56.lock.internal`? I'm assuming that by 'this does not work', it just times out which alludes to the above.

Comment: Let me update this thread with the error. That will help out more @ErmiyaEskandary.

Comment: And can you show me how you’re exactly using it? And how it works if you just change the host name using the writer’s endpoint?

Comment: Let me do an update and see if I can show it through that process.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve here? From what you've explained so far, it feels like it might be the wrong direction of travel.

Comment: The problem is if I use the CNAME record it doesn't work being `rds-dev-mysql56.lock.internal`. When I use the Configuration Endpoint (that is the same for the CNAME record) referencing the endpoint `rds-dev-mysql56.cluster-23423423fd.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`, it works. I just want to know why and if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any easy way to figure this out but I guess CNAME records don't work with RDS IAM Authentication which is annoying. The only way for this is to work is to do the following:

1. Install the AWS Toolkit for IntelliJ or embed the Writer Instance configuration endpoint (which will be a pain so it will be better to utilize the AWS Toolkit instead to assume the correct role where the RDS cluster resides.) You can find more info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-jetbrains/latest/userguide/rds-connection.html
2. When using the AWS IntelliJ toolkit, I click on the RDS Cluster I want to connect via assuming IAM Role and presto, works much faster this way. The only thing I need to do is change the `User`:
   [image]

I just wanted a simple way to connect using CNAME but this will do the trick instead.